# Update session from change in database next auth

Tags: session, next.js, next-auth

How do I update the session automatically or get the most updated session based on changes in the database?

I am building an application where a user can fill out a form to request 'instructor' role access and I can approve it by updating their role to be 'instructor' from the mongodb database. Before getting approved, their 'instructor' role is set to 'pending' and I change it to 'approved' in the database. However, when using role-based access with next auth, the session does not get updated automatically when the database is updated.

I am able to change the user's role to 'instructor' when they fill out the form (below) but I want to set its subfield to 'pending' and only change it to 'approved' after I update it in mongodb. However, I don't know how to inform the session of this change in the database since it is not happening while the users themselves are logged in on their own account.

```
            await update({
                ...session,
                user:{
                    ...session?.user,
                    role: 'instructor'
                }
            })
```